# Finding the spring compression length for an object to reach $U = 0$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy, spring

I have a question on the following, pertaining to only parts c and d (b was shown to provide the mass of the asteroid and radius):

-

[image]

I'm going to define the mass of the asteroid here as $M_A$ and the radius of the asteroid here as $R_A$.

My thought process is as follows:

- The object underwent work to go from radius $R_A$ to radius $r$ (where $U(r) = 0$)
- The object's energy at the initial state is its gravitational potential energy at $R_A$ and the energy of the spring. $E_i = -\frac{GMm}{R_A} + \frac{1}{2}kx^2$ thusly
- The object no longer has any potential energy at its final state, so all of its energy must be kinetic, equal to $\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = E_f$
- The energies are likely equal to eachother ($E_i = E_f$) since the energy of the system should be conserved?... It underwent work, but that was due to the extra stored potential by the spring?.. perhaps that's not true.

Which of my assumptions are wrong, and how can I go about tackling this logically? Note, this isn't homework but an example to enforce my learning. Thanks!

Comment: Your second and third points are mutually inconsistent.  The cleanest way to proceed is to abandon putting the zero of potential energy at the radius of the spacecraft, and putting the zero at infinity.  Then the system has non-zero PE at both locations.  You are right about energy: it is conserved.

Answer (score 0):

Conservation of energy should work at each step of the way. You have potential energy (a function of $r$) and the kinetic energy. Their sum is always constant. The escape velocity is such that the "final" energy (as $r\rightarrow \infty$) will be zero - no potential energy, no velocity. The intermediate level (where you are intercepting the satellite while "on your way to infinity and beyond") should correspond to a loss of kinetic energy equal to the gain in potential energy.

By setting the potential energy at infinity = 0 (you can pick any radius, but that is a good convention) you find $$PE = -KE$$ at every altitude.

With this convention, the initial and final energy (sum of KE and PE) would be = 0; and when you take into account the launch spring, with elastic energy EE, then you can say $$PE+KE+EE=0$$

And then all your results should follow.

Comment: Few questions about this:

1) Why would there be any kinetic energy at the initial state where its sitting on the asteroid and displaced on the spring? 

2) Why should there be a correspondence where there is a loss of potential energy equal to a gain in kinetic? The loss of potential energy should just be due to the distance it is moving from the asteroid's center?

3) Why does setting PE at r = infinity = 0 lead you to PE = -KE?

4) In the second equation, I'm solving for delta x, so how can I represent v in the kinetic energy formula.

Thanks so much! Excuse the ignorance.

Comment: Oh, and what would be the radius for GPE for your second equation? Would it be radius at r = RA? This is an initial state equation?

Comment: Here's what I gathered from what you said overall (I know it's horribly flawed, which is why I'd love some guidance):

1) Conservation of energy IS in play, since the work needed to be put on the system in order for the object to get to r = infinity is provided by the spring

2) The sum of energy is always constant, so Einital = Eintermediate = Efinal. Thus, GPE + EE = Einitial = Constant in magnitude

3) Setting PE at r = infinity means PE at r = RA is -GMm/RA.

4) Efinal has no potential and no kinetic energy, so it should be equal to 0.

5) Since energy is conserved, Einitial = 0.